# Что может быть причиной отказа удалённого сервера записать файл?

Tags: php, сервер, файловая-система

Простой код `<?php var_dump(file_put_contents("Info.txt", "123"));` выводит в браузер `bool(false)` при том, что файл находится в одной папке со скриптом и на него даны все права доступа (100777). Удалённый сервер на Debian'e, сервер apache2, php5.5

При чём, если файл отсутствует, он создаётся, но контент в него можно поместить только с флагом `FILE_APPEND` - если попытаться перезаписать его (без флага), то функция вернёт FALSE и файл будет пуст. Дажё если предварительно записать в него данные руками, попытка перезаписи его очищает и всё. Естественно на localhost'е такой проблемы нет.

**Что это за глюки, может кто сталкивался?**

Comment: мб заблокирован кем то другим?

Comment: Тогда не работал бы флаг FILE_APPEND

Comment: включите error_reporting E_ALL и display_error on. Выводятся ли ошибки?

Comment: Warning: file_put_contents(): Only 0 of 3 bytes written, possibly out of free disk space in /var/www/test.php on line 6 - Как же тогда оно позволяет дописывать в файл или редактировать его вручную? PS: Скрипт на сервере активно использует распределяемую память (shmop.dll), но не более 2,5 МБ,  а сам сайт и мегабайта не весит

Comment: @Iceman попробуйте почистить временные директории и увеличить memory_limit или же можно адресовать данный вопрос хостеру.

Comment: Короче, проблема нехватки памяти не понятна, но так как файлы создаются, пусть и с 0 байт, решил хранить свой массив в именах файлов и получать его через glob(Path/*); и basename(Path);